# cant access array from outside the loop firefox addon sdk

Tags: javascript, arrays, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i am new to firefox sdk, learning on google
i was trying to push strings from a for each loop in an array and reading it later on
but the array remains empty.

```
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "list-tabs",
  label: "List Tabs",
  icon: "./32.png",
  onClick: CollectURLs
});


function CollectURLs(){
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    var links = [];
    for each (var tab in tabs){
        if(tab.url.indexOf('google.com') != '-1'){
            tab.attach({
                    contentScript: 'for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("h3").length ; i= i+1){'+
                    'self.postMessage(document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute(\'href\'));'+
                    '}',
                    onMessage: function(message) {
                        console.log("URL: "+message);
                        links.push(message);
                    }               
            });
        }
    }
    console.log("ALL URLS:"+links);
}
```

output:

```
C:\addon-sdk\bin\hello>cfx run
Using binary at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'.
Using profile at 'c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\tmpp62fgl.mozrunner'.
JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 674: aUrl is undefined
console.log: hello: ALL URLS:
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.aa.com/
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.aa.org/
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.aaschool.ac.uk/
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.theaa.com/route-planner/
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.theaa.com/
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.aa.co.nz/
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.theaa.ie/
console.log: hello: URL: http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AA
console.log: hello: URL: http://www.alcoholics-anonymous.org.uk/
console.log: hello: URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA
```

and there is this array
console.log: hello: ALL URLS:
its empty and its being printed out before the loop is finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the eventing system to communicate between the content-script and the add-on. Read the 'Communicating with the add-on' section here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

[image: from their docs]

I think your code becomes (untested):

```
require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
  id: "list-tabs",
  label: "List Tabs",
  icon: "./32.png",
  onClick: CollectURLs
});
//moved these out of the method
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
var self = require("sdk/self"); 


function CollectURLs(){
    var links = [];
    for each (var tab in tabs){
        if(tab.url.indexOf('google.com') != '-1'){
            worker = tab.attach({ //change here
                    contentScript: 'for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("h3").length ; i= i+1){'+
                    'self.postMessage(document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute(\'href\'));'+
                    '}',
                    onMessage: function(message) {
                        //console.log("URL: "+message);
                        //links.push(message);
                        self.port.emit("url", message); //change here
                    }               
            });
            //change here
            worker.on("url", function(message) {
                links.push(message);
                console.log('current link list: ', links);
            });
        }
    }
    console.log("empty array expected because the event emitting is async:" + links);
}
```